# What exactly does the AddHint() method in Google OR-Tools' CP-SAT solver do?

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools, cp-sat

I have an optimization problem that I am solving with CP-SAT and I am using the Python interface. Moreover, I know a good feasible solution coming from a heuristic and I want the solver to start its search from this solution.

**How can I achieve this? Ideally, I would like to specify the initial value right after defining the variable, and not after the model is constructed. Is there a way to do it like this?**

I tried with the AddHint() method but it is not clear to me what it does exactly: the solver just ignores the hint and finds another initial solution. I also found the thread [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/3277) but it remains unanswered.

As a minimal working example, consider the optimization problem:

$ \max\limits_{(x, y) \in \Bbb Z^2 \cap [0, 10]^2 } \{x \: | \: x + y = 10  \}.$

The code implementation is the following:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

class SolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    """Print intermediate solutions."""

    def __init__(self, x):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self._solution_count = 1     
        self.x = x   

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        """Called at each new solution."""
 
        print("Solution " + str(self._solution_count) + " ---> " + str(self.Value(self.x))    )
       
        print("")
        self._solution_count += 1
        
    
model = cp_model.CpModel()

x = model.NewIntVar(0, 10, "x")
y = model.NewIntVar(0, 10, "y")

# Maximize x
model.Maximize(x)

# Hint 
model.AddHint(x, 1)

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
printer = SolutionPrinter(x)

solver.Solve(model, printer)
print(f"x = {solver.Value(x)} and y = {solver.Value(y)}")
```

The output here is

> Solution 1 ---> 10
>
> x = 10 and y = 0

Instead, it should find that $y = 9$ makes $(x, y)$ feasible and print that

> Solution 1 ---> 1

and only then keep looking.

**EDIT:** Based on the suggestion of @LaurentPerron, I added the options

```
solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 1
solver.log_callback = print
```

but this returns

> Starting CP-SAT solver v9.6.2534
>
> Parameters: log_search_progress: true num_search_workers: 1
>
> Initial optimization model '': (model_fingerprint: 0x871bcff12da75473)
>
> #Variables: 2 (#ints:1 in objective)
>
> - 2 in [0,10]
>
> Starting presolve at 0.00s
>
> The solution hint is complete and is feasible.
>
> [ExtractEncodingFromLinear] #potential_supersets=0
> #potential_subsets=0
>
> #at_most_one_encodings=0 #exactly_one_encodings=0 #unique_terms=0 #multiple_terms=0 #literals=0 time=1e-06s
>
> [Symmetry] Graph for symmetry has 2 nodes and 0 arcs.
>
> [Symmetry] Symmetry computation done. time: 4.9e-06 dtime: 1.2e-07
>
> [Probing] deterministic_time: 0 (limit: 1) wall_time: 1.1e-06 (0/0)
>
> [DetectDuplicateConstraints] #duplicates=0 #without_enforcements=0
> time=6e-06s
>
> [DetectDominatedLinearConstraints] #relevant_constraints=0
> #work_done=0 #num_inclusions=0 #num_redundant=0 time=3.7e-06s
>
> [ProcessSetPPC] #relevant_constraints=0 #num_inclusions=0 work=0
> time=7e-07s
>
> [FindBigLinearOverlap] #blocks=0 #saved_nz=0 #linears=0
> #work_done=0/1e+09 time=6e-07s
>
> [MergeClauses] #num_collisions=0 #num_merges=0 #num_saved_literals=0
> work=0/100000000 time=4e-07s
>
> [ExpandObjective] #propagations=0 #entries=0 #tight_variables=0
> #tight_constraints=0 #expands=0 #issues=0 time=5.4e-06s
>
> Presolve summary:
>
> - 0 affine relations were detected.
> - rule 'objective: variable not used elsewhere' was applied 1 time.
> - rule 'presolve: 2 unused variables removed.' was applied 1 time.
> - rule 'presolve: iteration' was applied 1 time.
>
> Presolved optimization model '': (model_fingerprint:
> 0xfc4715b25d7c8ae9)
>
> #Variables: 0 ( in objective)
>
> Preloading model.
>
> #Bound   0.00s best:-inf  next:[10,10]    initial_domain
>
> [Symmetry] Graph for symmetry has 0 nodes and 0 arcs.
>
> Starting to load the model at 0.00s
>
> Starting sequential search at 0.00s
>
> #1       0.00s best:10    next:[]          fixed_bools:0/0
>
> Solution 1 ---> 10
>
> #Done    0.00s
>
> CpSolverResponse summary:
>
> status: OPTIMAL
>
> objective: 10
>
> best_bound: 10
>
> integers: 1
>
> booleans: 0
>
> conflicts: 0
>
> branches: 0
>
> propagations: 0
>
> integer_propagations: 1
>
> restarts: 0
>
> lp_iterations: 0
>
> walltime: 0.0025853
>
> usertime: 0.0025854
>
> deterministic_time: 0
>
> gap_integral: 0
>
> solution_fingerprint: 0x2a5128eb91a71559
>
> x = 10 and y = 0

Thus, the problem still remains.

Comment: Please try the same recommendations: log_search_progress:true, num_search_workers:1 and note that your hint is not complete

Comment: @LaurentPerron thanks, will try. However, the incomplete hint was on purpose: in my problem, I want to supply a minimum number of variables after which the remaining ones are completely determined via equality constraints. I was expecting CP SAT to find them easily. Would this change the solution in the link you suggested?

Comment: Have you checked the second part ? Number of workers, which one finds the on solution first ?

Comment: Hi @LaurentPerron. I tried your suggestion but nothing. Please see the modified code. Also, please could you comment on my question above? (the one with the minimum number of variables that determine all of the variables). It is still not clear to me what am I supposed to find. I am a newbie with CP - SAT.

Comment: Yes, the model is so trivial, it is empty after presolve, and unfortunately, presolve does not follow the hint currently.

Comment: @LaurentPerron  Super thanks for being so active in this community. It is really a dream to have you answering questions for everyone here! The problem of the  solver not following the hint is also occurring with my real scheduling problem, which is way bigger (around 30K variables). In fact, it is taking ages to beat my initial greedy solution. This is why it is relevant to me having the option to make the solver start from the solution I give. What are my options here then?

Comment: Can you send me the model ?

Comment: Hi @LaurentPerron. Currently it would be very painful to send you the actual model because of its integration with other products. Plus, I also think that it wouldn't be fair to take so much of your time. I will thus try to build a similar example on which the same problem arises. Please give me a bit of time. I have already tried with something much simpler and the hint worked as expected, so I will complicate it more in the hope to get something to send. Thanks!

Comment: you know, model.ExportToFile('file.pb.txt') and it is done. But I do not want any confidential info.

Comment: @LaurentPerron Sent!

Comment: Received, and the hints appear infeasible. If I reduce the domain of hinted variables to their hinted values, the solver returns infeasibility.

Comment: Will check. Thanks!

Comment: @LaurentPerron All good, definitely the heuristic had a problem that is now fixed.  Please write as an answer that I should check infeasibility: I would  then accept :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hints are actually wrong and infeasible. A good way to check it is to add the parameter `fix_variables_to_their_hinted_value:true` to the solver before solving.

In your case, it returns INFEASIBLE, thus showing the problem.